# testing launch files in install_space?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

The question I have is actually pretty short:

> Is there a way to run roslaunch checks in an install space?

Let me give you a short rationale of my current thoughts:

In ROS, there are three different types of tests you can have (afaik):

1. Unit Tests (using [gtest](http://wiki.ros.org/gtest) or [unittest](http://wiki.ros.org/unittest)) for testing functionality
2. [rostests](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest) for testing ROS Nodes and other ROS stuff (e.g. publishers/subscribers)
3. [roslaunch checks](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch#Catkin) (very bottom of the page) using `roslaunch_add_file_check`

IMO, 1. and 2. should be run in the build/devel space, as those test targets and launchfiles should not be installed (even though there are some packages doing this, e.g. [gazebo_plugins/test/set_model_state_test](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/CMakeLists.txt#L358-L360), which then does fail as the required test executable is not, and cannot be, installed.)

However, for 3. it would be beneficial to check this in the install space as well. This would help to detect missing install tags of executables, launch files and yaml files.

How can I achieve this? `catkin_make run_tests` is always running in devel/build/src.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241467/testing-launch-files-in-install_space?/) by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-08-15**:
@William @tfoote maybe some insights from you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The testing frameworks are not available when installed. If you want to test a packages installed resources you can create another package which depends on the package you want to test, and then test it on top of the installed version of the dependency. So that the package with the tests is still in the buildspace but it can test the resources from the install space.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-08-19**:
@tfoote thanks.